# Dice simulation and using array for values

Tags: java, arrays

This is my first time putting a code together for Java based on my own so i was hoping if you someone would be kind enough to review and provide feedback or constructive criticism on this code.

The goal is to roll 2 dices and 10k times. add pairs and display their frequency.

Code runs fine but maybe i am over looking some logical error or a better way to do this

```
/**
 * Use the Random Number generator to write a java application that simulates a pair of dice.
 * Throwing the pair of dice 10,000 times- Add the values for the pair
 * Print the frequency at the end of 10,000 runs
 * @author 
 *
 */

import java.util.Random;

public class diceSimulation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**
         * Declare variables and store dice max roll in Thousand
         */
        final int THOUSAND = 10000;
        int counter, dice1, dice2;

        //initiate an array with elements to keep count
        int [] diceValue = new int [7];

        // display welcome message. no other purpose but trial
        welcome ();

        // create new instance of random 
        Random rollDice = new Random();

        /**
         * Set counter to start from 1 and go till desired constant number
         * Rolling two separate dices and storing values in dice1 & dice 2 respectively
         */
        for (counter=1; counter<=THOUSAND;counter++){

            dice1=rollDice.nextInt(6) +  1;
            dice2=rollDice.nextInt(6) + 1;

            // If statement to check if values are the same or not
            if (dice1==dice2){
                // IF values are same then go into for loop and store value in array element
                for (int i=1; i<=6; i++){
                    if (dice1 == i && dice2 == i){
                        // add value for the number displayed into the array
                        diceValue [i] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        // Display results totals of paired rolls 
        for (int a=1; a<diceValue.length; a++){
            System.out.println(" You rolled set of " + a + " " + diceValue[a] + " times");
        }

    }

    public static void welcome () {
        System.out.println("welcome to dice world!");
    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest to post this on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you move the code into the `ReviewCode` section, because the code is running and you just want feedback.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on  codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Having voted to close, I can't help but review: `final int THOUSAND = 10000;` really? a thousand  point ones?

Comment: Isn't 10000 Ten Thousand ? :D

Comment: Thanks Gerald for fixing the code part

Comment: John3136: It is working but might have logical error or coding errors. If you think its appropriate to post on codereview then i will do so but hoping to get some perspective here.

Comment: `might have logical error or coding errors` What makes you think so? All code "might" have errors. Do you have any tests to confirm correct behavior?

Comment: THOUSAND is not a good variable name. Call it something like ROLLSNUMBER so you express the variable purpose. You are using the javadoc syntax in some comments: why? Also, more important thing, the answer below is right.

Comment: Will change the name. Using javadoc to display as much info as possible but then again its all new tech and i am still learning on how to properly utilize it. will keep your suggestion in mind for future.

Answer (score 1):

```
// If statement to check if values are the same or not
        if (dice1==dice2){
            // IF values are same then go into for loop and store value in array element
            for (int i=1; i<=6; i++){
                if (dice1 == i && dice2 == i){
                    // add value for the number displayed into the array
                    diceValue [i] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

This whole part is a little bit redundant.

After that you know that dice1==dice2 you only iterate over i to stop when it's equal to both and then you add 1 to diceValue[i] that is assured to be the same as diceValue[dice1] or diceValue[dice2].
That can be made directly by `diceValue[dice1]++` (again, after knowing that dice1==dice2

Comment: Thanks Malarres. Your point did cross my mind but i was unaware of how to implement it. Thanks for your suggestion.